# What is the best way of storing lots of text data? Mysql / Json file?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, storage

I am currently building a web app which will rely on people saving a lot of text information onto the website server, similar to Wikipedia. I was wondering what is the best way to actually store the information which they enter.

Lets say as an example someone adds an entry of 5000 words. Shall I just add this into a "text" input or make a JSON file which needs to be read?

I'm quite new to this kind of thing so I want to balance out speed and security.

Comment: I'd probably go via a TEXT input personally but I assume you'd be making people log in to submit such things?

Comment: Yeah the entries will be attached to an account ID.

Comment: It's gonna be a varied answer I think as both ways are pretty much acceptable to do it. Only other thing I can suggest is to use prepared statements

Comment: Okay. I think I'm going to use the TEXT input in MySQL. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Make sure you use either mysqli or PDO. mysql_ is deprecated. Also go for prepared statements as it'll make your life so much easier in the short and long run.

Comment: In which regard should it be the best way? This is what you should add to avoid the question being too broad. You might want to optimize insertion speed, retrieval speed, space used, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Storing it as JSON will be better if you will be using that data later.Which will be easy to process. Wondering which database are you using

Comment: The data will be accessed when the user wants to view their entries. Should JSON still be used? Where would I store the json files? What if someone finds the directory of the files? They will be able to view everyone's private entries

Comment: Mostly I use mongodb which relies on json to store data. I think you can store data under varchar format in an SQL database and decode it in the front end

Answer (score 2):

With file like images and big text, the name of the file is usually generated by the system automatically and stored in a database while the file is stored in the normal file system.

For example this is a database table for users:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ Name ║  Surname  ║      Descr_file      ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ Luca ║ Mc.Donald ║ descr_42312jf234.txt ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

and descr_42312jf234.txt is stored in the file system.

If you don't need to maintain some structured info in the text file, because is only a description for example, you shouldn't use JSON encoding.

About security, you can generate very long name, with SHA-2 for example, that are very difficult to be discovered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL , then you can save it as TEXT data type.